# Как скрыть элементы, которые находятся за пределами ScrollView?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Юзаю Unity3D, NGUI. Имеется ScrollView, в нем вложена сетка UIGrid, туда динамически впиливаю около 1000 нетекстурированных спрайтов с необходимой инфой в лейблах. При прокрутке всё это дело очень сильно тормозит, FPS падает до 8-10. Вопрос: как мне повысить производительность? Может скрыть все элементы, которые находятся за пределами видимости? Если да, то как? Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Я написал этот код, он работает, но очень некорректно. Элементы скрываются, но при прокрутке расстояние между элементами нарушается. Там вообще рандом какой-то. Меня еще смущает, что всё это на апдейте, а по другому нет идей как реализовать

```
public bool the_test_bool = false;
public int counts;

void Update ()
{


    UIRoot mRoot = GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(UIRoot)) as UIRoot;
    float ratio = (float)mRoot.activeHeight / Screen.height;
    int width = (int)Mathf.Ceil (Screen.width * ratio);
    int height = (int)Mathf.Ceil (Screen.height * ratio);


    float cHeight = NAVI.grid_main.GetComponent<UIGrid> ().cellHeight;


    float y = NAVI.grid_main.transform.parent.GetComponent<UIPanel> ().clipOffset.y;
    float cBot = y - (height / 2f);
    float cTop = y + (height / 2f);

    if (!the_test_bool) {
        counts = NAVI.grid_main.transform.childCount;
        if (counts > 1) {
            the_test_bool = true;
            counts = NAVI.grid_main.transform.childCount;
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++) {

        float itemXCenter = (cHeight * counter);
        float itemBCenter = itemXCenter + (cHeight * 2f);
        float itemTCenter = itemXCenter - (cHeight * 2f);

        bool isVis = 
            (itemTCenter < cTop && itemBCenter > cBot) || 
            (itemBCenter > cBot && itemTCenter < cTop) || 
            (itemTCenter < cTop && itemBCenter > cBot);
        NAVI.grid_main.transform.GetChild (i).gameObject.SetActive (isVis);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут 2 варианта:

1. Действительно скрыть элементы (Например, проверкой на попадание в rect видимости).
2. Перемещать не сами элементы, а камеру (Но придется использовать другой подход). В NGUI был пример где-то похожий с камерой.